# Recreating a program to run a ssis package. Getting a LoadPackage error

Tags: c#, ssis

```
using System;

using System.Windows.Forms;

using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Application = System.Windows.Forms.Application;

    private void Execute_Package()
    {
        string pkgLocation = @"c:\test.dtsx";

        Package pkg;
        Application app;
        DTSExecResult pkgResults;
        Variables vars;

        app = new Application();
        pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);

        vars = pkg.Variables;
        vars["A_Variable"].Value = "Some value";

        pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null, vars, null, null, null);

        if (pkgResults == DTSExecResult.Success)
            Console.WriteLine("Package ran successfully");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Package failed");
    }

 pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);  <-- LoadPackage error
```

I copied this example into vs2013 added the reference and I'm getting an error on the `LoadPackage` line:

```
 does not contain a definition for 'LoadPackage' and no extension
 method 'LoadPackage' accepting a first argument of type
 'System.Windows.Forms.Application' could be found (are you missing a
 using directive or an assembly reference?
```

Is there another referece I need to add?  I'm googling but not finding.  Maybe I'm just tired.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Application = System.Windows.Forms.Application;
```

to:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Application = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just running DTEXEC utility from code. That's what I always do.

Sorry I cant provide an example, at the moment I'm on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem was I had the wrong using statement.

I was using using Application = System.Windows.Forms.Application;
I should have used using Application = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application

A friend a worked found the problem.